# windows 7 desktop freezes / hangs for about 90 seconds ~5-10 times per day, no hardware sensor logs

Tags: windows-7, cpu, freeze, hardware-failure

My windows 7 desktop started freezing occasionally. The "freeze" proceeds like this...

1. Application stops responding to clicks, but screen is still updating and media is still playing
2. Screen & Video stops updating but mouse is still moving and audio still playing
3. Audio and Mouse stop. At this point everything is frozen, screen is still on.

It stays in the final state for about 90 seconds before everything just comes back. When it does come back, there are no errors reported, and any mouse clicks I made (while mouse was still working) seem to get handled (or attempt to get handled).

Things I have done...

- I installed Open Hardware Monitor and the only thing it can report is
  basically nothing. For those 90 seconds it has no record whatsoever
  of my CPU/GPU load / Temperature, etc. So it has been of little use.
- I ran the windows memory test, and it reported no errors.
- I replaced the main HDD with a SSD (cloned the entire drive)
- Added thermal paste on the CPU

Comment: You wrote "I replaced the main HDD with a SSD (cloned the entire drive)"   ... That just clones errors.  See if you can try a fresh installation of Windows 7 on one of the disks and then try again letting it run.

Comment: Are you referring to 'Event Viewer' when you say there are no errors reported when it resumes from freeze?

Comment: What does Task Manager tell you in terms of CPU usage? Can you launch it after performing a cold boot of your PC, leave it open "on top", and tell us what's the CPU and RAM load when your freezes occur?

Comment: The description sounds exactly like a defect HDD. As you have already changed the drive also make sure to replace the SATA cable. And disconnect all other SATA devices. A fresh Windows 7  (or Windows 10 the upgrade is still possible for free) would be recommended.

Comment: @John I never considered that I might be a software problem, but yes I guess I might need to upgrade.

Comment: @patkim You're right! At the exact time as the freeze, the windows system log shows an error:

{Registry Hive Recovered} Registry hive (file): '\??\C:\Windows\System32\config\COMPONENTS' was corrupted and it has been recovered. Some data might have been lost.

Comment: So as you noted and I noted above (copying a clone copies errors), now is a good time to consider upgrading.  Does my answer above help you?